# Dump data to specific Cell in a different Sheet in the same Workbook

Tags: excel, vba

I was looking for a VBA script to write data from a table to specified cell in a worksheet.

[image]

For eg: In the image table - column 1 is serial number, column 2 is data to be written, column 3 is sheet to which it should be written and column 4 is the cell in the corresponding sheet.

I am looking for a VBA script to write '1' from row 1 & column 2 to cell "A1" in sheet "A".

Answer (score -2):

Here's code for it:

```
Sub Dump2Print()
LastRow = Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
Dim rng As Range: Set rng = Application.Range("Dump!A1:A" & LastRow)
Dim i As Integer
Set wb = ActiveWorkbook
For i = 1 To rng.Rows.Count
    MyValue = rng.Cells(RowIndex:=i, ColumnIndex:="B").Value       
    MySheet = rng.Cells(RowIndex:=i, ColumnIndex:="C").Value       
    MyRange = rng.Cells(RowIndex:=i, ColumnIndex:="D").Value       
    Set ws = wb.Sheets(MySheet)       
    ws.Activate       
    ws.Range(MyRange) = MyValue
Next
End Sub
```

This code will look at all the data in the table in sheet named "Dump" and read values from column "B","C" & "D".